# Can I import a .vrm model?

Tags: add-on, import

I'd like to import a .vrm model. Is there any plugin that allows this?
I'd also like to know if it's possible to convert a .vrm to a .fbx or something else, however just being able to import it into blender is good enough.

Comment: this VRM https://dwango.github.io/en/vrm/vrm_about/ ?

Comment: yes I'm pretty sure, mine is from VROID studio, and it exported as a VRM, so probably. I already looked on this website but I find it hard to understand, its probably google translated or something as there's also a japanese version of this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bryan had the right idea but added an extra step. You can just change the extension to GLB and import the file as a GLB straight into Blender. There is also an addon that will allow you to import VRM files directly into Blender. So these two methods are the best two methods for importing VRM into Blender.

Comment: at the time this question was posted (3 years ago) there was no addon to import VRMs into blender haha but i got it now

Answer (score 3):

if you change the extention from .vrm to .glb and open in Windows Paint 3D, you can then export it to FBX and import to Blender.

Comment: changing it to .glb and opening it in Paint 3D works fine, however, Paint 3D doesn't allow me to export to .fbx, so i exported it to .obj. When I tried importing it in blender it gave me an error. I've never tried to import a .obj in blender before, nor worked with .obj's, so I'm not sure if I need to import the .mtl too or not, but importing with .mtl doesn nothing and importing without .mtl gives an error.

Comment: Worked for me.  Paint3D totally has the option to save as fbx.  Thanks man, that saved me a lot of time. :-)