# How do I install the add ons into blender?

Tags: add-on

I want to install add ons for importing .vrm files.

I need to know how to get the add-on from my macbook's files into blender and install it correctly. When I bring up the file, it is not a zip file even though I downloaded the zip file.

Comment: The instructions differ somewhat between addons, however generally all you have to do is go to `Prefernces > Add-on's` and click the _Install_ button at the top. You can then choose the addon file from your computer (usually a .zip file - no need to extract.....  most of the time).

Comment: If the file is a zip file, don't decompress it, as it is probably a series of scripts that need to be installed together. Just open the system preferences and install from there and select the compressed file.

Comment: or read the manual page: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/addons.html?highlight=addon

Comment: worth reading : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116500/can-i-import-a-vrm-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason that I couldn't use the zip file was because Safari automatically opened them. If anyone else is having this problem, open Safari, click preferences, and uncheck the box that says "Open 'safe' files after downloading".