# How do I import .vrm to blender?

Tags: modeling, animation

I've tried blender 2.93.8 and 2.93.7 and in add-ons I can't check the box for Shotariya's Material Combiner which a youtube video showed to work, but I just get an error. If I just try to import .vrm it gives me a VRM License Confirmation and says something about checking otherPermissionURL, there is an option "import anyway", but with that I don't get my model I only get the kind of "skeleton" of my model. Also this is my first time using blender I've been at this for about 3-4 hours now and can't find any help on the internet nor fix this myself. Is there any way to get my model to show up?

Edit: I forgot to say that the .vrm is from VRoid Studio and I have no idea if this is useful or not

Comment: Unfortunately, the provided information are not enough to give an answer. Please provide a link to the add-on you've installed and the exact error message.  It could be that there is a bug in the add-on or that you need a license key for activation, if this is a commercial add-on that you need to pay for, but those are just a guesses based on your description. Perhaps the workaround in this answer works for your as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116500/can-i-import-a-vrm-model

Comment: So I don't know which one you need so I'll give you all 3 of the add-ons I got

Comment: https://github.com/Grim-es/material-combiner-addon https://github.com/saturday06/VRM_Addon_for_Blender https://github.com/absolute-quantum/cats-blender-plugin (I downloaded the latest versions also tried material combiner 2.1.21 and vrm add-on for blender 2.1.11  -  The messages it gives me are Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files\Blender2.93\2.93\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable mod=__import__(module_name) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'material-combiner-addon-2'

Comment: The message I get for trying to import the .vrm is VRM License Confirmation   Is this VRM allowed to edited? Please check its "otherPermissionURL" value. For more infromation please check following URL. otherPermissionUrl: (it allows me to type here but there is written) undefined

Answer (score 0):

Ok so idk if this will still help after months, but if your vrm file is like a few kbs just resave your model from vroid, and what i did was increase my polygons a tiny bit, but i dont think you have to do that.